# UserDetailsService throwing UsernameNotFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We're using Spring Boot and InMemoryAuthentication to store users. 
At some point, we need to check the granted authorities of specific users. 
We tried doing it by getting the UserDetailsService bean (was autowired) and calling loadUserByUsername(username). However, UsernameNotFoundException is thrown in all the attempts.

To debug the cause, tried to reduce doing it even in the overriden configureGlobal() of our WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, right after adding the user:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("1234").roles("AGENT"); 
    UserDetails ud = auth.inMemoryAuthentication().getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername("user1");
```

The UsernameNotFoundException is thrown even there, right after the in-memory user was set.
And as said, the same happens in other places in the code which use the autowired userDetailsServiceBean.

Any advice how to get the above snippet to work? or in general, how to get the credentials of in-memory users?

thanks!

NOTE: we do not have any custom UserDetailsService

**UPDATE**

The class is annotated with @EnableWebSecurity :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

referring to the links suggested, tried also other styles:

```
@Autowired 
public void whatever(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {      
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("1234").roles("AGENT"); 
    UserDetails ud = auth.inMemoryAuthentication().getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername("user1");
    LOGGER.info(ud);
```

and also:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {      
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("1234").roles("AGENT"); 
    UserDetails ud = auth.inMemoryAuthentication().getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername("user1");
    LOGGER.info(ud);
```

However, the exception is consistently thrown in each:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: user1
at org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(InMemoryUserDetailsManager.java:122) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: please share your spring configuration classes

Comment: updated the question with the class annotations

Comment: You cannot load a user from the `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method; the UserDetailsService has not been initialized yet.

Comment: You have not provided the full stack trace of the exception thrown. The info in these will provide the root cause. Is the exception being thrown inside the overriden 'configure' method?